# Minimal Number of Extract + Inserts required to sort a list

Tags: algorithm, sorting

### Context

this problem arises from trying to minimize number of expensive function calls

### Problem Definition

Please note that extract_and_insert != swap. In particular, we take the element from position "from", insert it at position "to", and *SHIFT* all intermediate elements.

```
int n;
int A[n]; // all elements are integer and distinct



function extract_and_insert(from, to) {

  int old_value = A[from]

  if (from < to) {
    for(int i = from; i < to; ++i)
      A[i] = A[i+1];
    A[to] = old_value;
  } else {
    for(int i = from; i > to; --i)
      A[i] = A[i-1];
     A[to] = old_value;
  }
}
```

### Question

We know there are O(n log n) algorithms for sorting a list of numbers.

Now: is there an O(n log n) function, which returns the *minimum number of calls* to extract_and_insert required to sort the list?

Comment: @AlmaDo: that's not the question. The question is: "Is there an O(n log n) algorithm which can return the *minimum number of calls* to `extract_and_insert` required to sort a list?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [The minimum number of "insertions" to sort an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392743/the-minimum-number-of-insertions-to-sort-an-array)

Comment: @Dukeling: indeed, the two questions are the same. It's my fault for not finding the original question. However, given that there's already an answer posted, let's not delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**.

This problem is essentially equivalent to finding the [longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) (LIS) in an array, and you can use algorithms to solve that.

#### Why is this question equivalent to longest increasing subsequence?

Because each `extract_and_insert` operation will, at its most effective use, correct the **relative** position of **exactly** one element in the array. In other words, when we consider the length of the longest increasing subsequence of the array, each operation will increase that length by 1. So, the minimum number of required calls is:

```
length_of_array - length_of_LIS
```

and therefore by finding the length of LIS, we will be able to find the minimum number of operations required.

Do read up the linked Wikipedia page to see how to implement the algorithm.