# minimum number of actions needed to sort an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, greedy

I'm trying to practice solving a problem from Codeforces. It is to sort an array by moving the elements of the array either to the beginning or to the end of the array. At first thought i thought it is longest increasing subsequence but it's not working in some cases. For example if the input is 4,1,2,5,3 the LIS is 3 but the answer for the problem is moving 4 to the end of the array and then 5 to the end of the array which gives us 2. Also i was trying out on the example 1,6,4,5,9,8,7,3,2 in this LIS is 1,4,5,9 but the answer for the problem is 7 moves between 1 and 2. I got to know that i should use greedy approach but couldn't quite relate. Could someone help me in this ?

Comment: i think you should try quick sort..

Comment: @art - I don't think quicksort will always return the minimum number of moves needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The minimum number of "insertions" to sort an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392743/the-minimum-number-of-insertions-to-sort-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see that, to sort the array, each element is only need to be moved **at most** one.

So, to minimize the number of movement, we need to find the maximum number of element that is not moved. And those element is the **longest continuous sequence** , which is the sequence `(a0, a1, ... an)` with `a(i + 1) = ai + 1`.

For example,

(4,1,2,5,3), longest continuous sequence is (1,2,3)

(5,2,1,3,4), longest continuous sequence is (2,3,4)

So we have our code:

```
int[]longest = new int[n + 1];
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    longest[data[i]] = longest[data[i] - 1] + 1;
    result = max (longest[data[i]] , result);
}

print "Minimum number of move is " + (n - result)
```

**Explanation:**

In the code, I am using an array `longest` which index `ith` stores the longest continuous sequence, which ends at `value i`.

So, we can see that `longest[i] = longest[i - 1] + 1`.

And the result for the longest continuous sequence is the maximum value stored in `longest` array.

Comment: Thankyou Pham Trung this is correct. Could you pls explain more clearly ? are you telling that the solution is (n - Longest Continuous Subsequence) ?

Comment: @RiderForest yes. What else do you not understand?

Comment: i am trying to understand these lines "longest[data[i]] = longest[data[i] - 1] + 1;" and "result = max (longest[data[i]] , result);"

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem on Codeforces during the contest itself. Nice problem.

Think **'longest continuous sub-sequence'**. The answer is n-*longest continuous sub-sequence*.

 Example:
Take 1 2 3 7 5 6 4. The longest continuous sub-sequence is 1 2 3 4. *Now you can shift the remaining elements in a particular order to get the sorted array always*. At least that is how I thought of it intuitively

Here is a snippet of the main code:

```
    int n=in.readInt();
    int[] a=new int[n+1];
    int[] cnt=new int[n+1];
    int max=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        a[i]=in.readInt();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cnt[a[i]]=1+cnt[a[i]-1];
        max=Math.max(max,cnt[a[i]]);
    }
    out.printLine((n-max));
```

Hope that helps!